# Unknown database PHP, PDO

Tags: php, pdo, wamp

Es muy simple mi problema, tengo wamp, y cuando creo una base de datos en phpmyadmin, en la interfaz de phpmyadmin aparece la base de datos con sus tablas y registros, pero cuando intento hacer PDO conection con esa base de datos me arroja, UnknowDatabase, he cuidado muy bien de escribir todo correctamente

```
$conection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=devsinumedical','root','');
```

he intentado reiniciar el server wamp, pero no da resultado, parece como que no puede reconocer que ahí hay una base de datos que se llama así, está bien escrita, no tiene errores, he intentado copiar y pegar el nombre directamente de phpmyadmin pero tampoco, tenia una base de datos previamente, y esa si la reconoce, pero intente crearle una tabla nueva a esa base de datos y resulta en lo mismo, no puede reconocer esa tabla en específcio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ejecuta esta consulta en phpMyAdmin para ver en qué puerto está corriendo MySQL: **`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';`**

Comment: Se está ejecutando en el puerto 3308

Comment: Entonces tendrás que indicarle el puerto, de lo contrario es probable que esté asumiendo el puerto por defecto que es `3306` y por eso no encuentra la BD. Prueba así: **`$conection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=devsinumedical;port=3308','root','');`**

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la colaboración, si te interesa saber cual era el problema, "creo", es porque había un conflicto entre wamp y xampp ya que tenia ambos servidores instalados, no los tenia corriendo simultaneamente pero supongo que algo afectaba, pues desinstalé wamp y dejé xampp y corrió perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos en general, por intentar colaborar, si estan interesados en saber cual era la causa del conflicto, posiblemente se debe a que tenía dos servidores web instalados en mi pc, wamp y xampp, aunque no los estaba corriendo simultaneamente, sin dudas era la causa del conflicto, puesto que desinstalé wamp y me quedé con xampp y la consulta corrió perfectamente.

Answer (score -1):

Verifica la correcta escritura del dato que corresponde a `devsinumedical`; esto es, mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: Está correctamente escrito, todo minúsculas.

Comment: Creo que esto quedaría más como un comentario que como una respuesta

Comment: @JesidPolo entonces debes verificar el nombre de la base de datos es así o la forma correcta en como esta. Es decir que no sobren o falten letras; o ya "en caso extremo" no sea este mal el nombre de la misma.

Comment: @BetaM eso pensé, pero en la prueba local que realice en mi compu para ver si es el error; el cual por cierto fue `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'devsinumedical'` (desde luego en mi caso no existe tal BD). Me parecio que la solución para @JesidPolo es corrobore algun error de escritura e incluso que no sea así el nombre de la BD a la cual desea conectarse.

Comment: intenté crear una nueva base de datos con el nombre "sinumedical" y obtengo el mismo error, es improbable que sea un error de escritura.

Comment: Anexaré captura de pantalla de las bases de datos.

Comment: Saludos @JesidPolo; ya vi la captura de pantalla; solo se me ocurren 2 cosas por probar la posibilidad que la última letra del nombre de la Base de Datos sea una **i** pero mayúscula y no una **L** minúscula y/o revises el **host** que estes apuntando al correcto (donde existe la BD).